# How to prove : P v ( P → Q ) by Natural Deduction

Tags: logic

Another of Tomassi's exercises I can't solve (Logic, page 109, Revision exercise III, 9)

: P v ( P → Q )

I have to use natural deduction and the only rules I know are:

• assumptions,

• modus ponendo ponens,

• modus tollendo tollens,

• double negation,

• reductio ad absurdum,

• conditional proof,

• v-introduction,

• v-elimination,

• and introduction,

• and elimination.

Tomassi's proof consists of 16 steps.

Thanks!

Comment: You have posted many questions regarding elementary logic homeworks on this site: many answers... no one accepted by you. If you are not interested in the answers, wht ask questions ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm really sorry I didn't know I had to do that.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Can you [edit] to show what you tried and where you got stuck? (That way we can explain what part of that you're confused about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the proof looks like strictly following Tomasello's rules:

{1} 1. ~(P v ( P → Q ))  Assumption for RAA

{2} 2. P  Assumption for RAA

{2} 3. P v ( P → Q )  2 vI

{1,2} 4. (P v ( P → Q )) & ~(P v ( P → Q ))  1,3 &I

{1} 5. ~P   2,4 RAA

{6} 6. P  Assumption

{7} 7. ~Q  Assumption for RAA

{6,7} 8. P & ~Q 6,7 &I

{6,7} 9. P 8 &E

{1,6,7} 10. P & ~P   5,9 &I

{1,6} 11. ~~Q   9,10 RAA

{1,6} 12. Q  DNE 11

{1} 13. P → Q  CP 6,12

{1} 14. P v ( P → Q )  13 vI

{1} 15. (P v ( P → Q )) & ~(P v ( P → Q ))  1,14 &I

{} 16. ~~(P v ( P → Q )) RAA 1,15

{} 17. P v ( P → Q )) DNE 16

Notice what I did there: on line 8 I pasted the ~Q to the P from line 6, but then on line 9 I isolated that P again ... the whole effect of which was to make the P now dependent on the assumption of ~Q (after all, I did derive that P from P & ~Q, and I got P & ~Q from (among other things ~Q), so yes, it is dependent on ~Q). And that means that the contradiction on line 10 is dependent on ~Q as well, which is why we can say that the contradiction is 'derived' from ~Q. Indeed, when we then apply RAA, we throw out this very dependency of ~Q.

On pages 63-64 Tomassi talks about this very strategy, and calls it *augmentation*. There, he used it for CP, for he demands that in order to apply CP, the depencies of the antecedent should be in the depencies of the consequent. On the top half of p.104 he mentions that the same must be true for RAA:

> The contradiction must depend upon the assumption if we are to apply RAA legitimately to that assumption.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't get  where line 9 comes from. According to Tomassi's text, in order to get line 9, it has to be deduced from line 7 and any other formulas available. However, I don't see how ~Q from line 7 is computed with  P & ~P line 8 to get ~~Q. What I mean is how is the assumption ~Q related to P & ~P so to produce ~~Q?

Comment: @DiegoRuizHaro Yeah, that's a weird one ... let me explain that in the Answer

Comment: @DiegoRuizHaro  OK, I very carefully read Tomassi, and found that indeed the depencies of the assumption should be a subset of the depencies of the contradiction, so that it indeed makes sense to say that P&~P is derived from ~Q. To do this, you use a little trick called augmentation .. I explain this in the updated Answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

Use v-elimination on **P v ~P**.

---

Alternatively, we can circumvent the lack of LEM using Double Negation :

1) **~ [P v ( P → Q )]** --- assumed [a]

2) **~Q** --- assumed [b]

3) **~P** --- assumed [c]

4) **P** --- assumed [d]

5) **~~Q** --- from the contradiction of 3) and 4) by RAA

6) **Q** --- from 5) by DNE, discharging [b]

7) **( P → Q )** --- from 4) and 6) by →-intro, discgarging [d]

8) **P v ( P → Q )** --- from 5) by v-intro.

Now we have a contradiction with 1) and we use RAA and DNE with 3) deriving :

9) **P** --- from 3), discharging [c]

10) **P v ( P → Q )** --- from 9) by v-intro.

Contradiction with 1) again : we apply RAA and DNE to 1) deriving :

> 11) **P v ( P → Q )** --- from 1), discharging [a].

Comment: As far as I know he can't prove the law of excluded-middle P v ~P (which is necessary to do v-elimination).

Comment: @BorisE. - why not ? DN is equiv to LEM.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks a lot! However it is not clear to me yet how do you get Q from 2 and 3? I'm sorry for the silly question but I'm just teaching myself logic and Tomassi's is the only reference I'm using. I have no mathematics background. So the only information I have is the one in Tomassi's text. For the moment, he hasn't shown how to get the sort of contradiction you got at 4.

Comment: @DiegoRuizHaro - I cannot find browsing Tomassi's book a reference list of rules. In [Natural deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) there is the rule that allows us to derive a formula whatever from a contradiction. In your case, if this rule is not available, you can simplu assume **~Q** and derive **Q** from it using the contradiction.

Comment: @DiegoRuizHaro Are you aware of [ex falso quodlibet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)?